# Building query strings in PHP

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a technique or function to do this or if I'm just going to have to have a ton of IF statements/arrays here-

I have a page called products.php and a few different filters I add in the query string.
All the filters (if chosen) could look like this:

```
products.php?cat=chairs&type=pine&search=Vienna+Range
```

Is there a simple way to build the query for use again?

I'm going to have buttons/a search box to change the filters I'm using, so will I have to build the URL and query up again for each filter?

For example I'd like to have:

```
<a href="products.php?cat=tables">Tables</a>
<a href="products.php?cat=beds">Beds</a>
<a href="products.php?cat=chairs">Chairs</a>
```

but also build the query so that it remembers my search term, wood type and range; so clicking on "Tables" would take me to

```
products.php?cat=chairs&type=pine&search=Vienna+Range.
```

Comment: What about the php function `http_build_query`?  http://php.net/http_build_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'cat'    => 'chair',
    'type'   => 'pine',
    'search' => 'Vienna Range',
);

print_r(http_build_query($params) . PHP_EOL);
```

You'll get this:

```
cat=chair&type=pine&search=Vienna+Range
```

Comment: So I would have to do build the query like that for each filter?

Comment: Well, I would do something like this:

```$params = array('new_search_param' => 'value'); $params = array_merge($_GET, $params);```

This way, the old search params will be preserved.

Comment: That's a bit over my head for someone at my level, but you made me look at http_build_query again which gives me what I want. I just have to check if a value it is entered as "NULL". Thank you!